# CMake: directories with targets dependent on each other's target

Tags: cmake

I have two folders, each containing some targets. One is a child folder of another. But I don't think it really matters for my problem. It applies to any two folders. Anyways, here's my dependencies:

- folder2/target1 -> folder1/target1
- folder1/target2 -> folder2/target1

From the targets point of view, these are completely normal dependencies. However, I don't know how to express this in CMake, since I can't `add_subdirectory()` each other in both folders, which would create a cyclic reference.

This is what I have:

```
folder1/CMakeLists.txt:
...
add_subdirectory(folder2)
...
```

```
folder2/CMakeLists.txt:
...
add_subdirectory(../ folder1)
...
```

And I'm using VS code with CMake extension. In fact, CMake doesn't seem to be able to detect the cyclic reference and keeps running forever and using up the RAM and eventually crashing VS code.

I'm converting an existing codebase from Bazel to CMake. And it's not possible, at least not practical, to change the folder structures. In Bazel, you don't need to add another folder in their BUILD file. You can simply specify a fully qualified target name.

What's the best way to achieve something similar in CMake? Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] and share the CMake code you have written so far or at least a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some misconceptions about how CMake works or is to be used. Maybe these come from your experience with Bazel (though I cannot tell).

The idea is that CMake traverses your project once, starting from the project's root and descending into subdirectories. It picks up targets (libraries, executables and custom ones) as it goes, orders them as appropriate and generates a build system.

Entering a parent directory using `add_subdirectory()` is unusual but not an error in itself. It is not needed in your case. Adding a subdirectory more than once is certainly wrong.

Whenever CMake visits a `CMakeLists.txt` by `add_subdirectory()`, it creates a new directory scope. Making CMake do so recursively will eventually exhaust the available memory as we've seen.

The following two `CMakeList.txt`s cover the case you describe:

In `folder1/CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
add_library(f1t1 foo.cpp)
add_executable(f1t2 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(f1t2 f2t1)
add_subdirectory(folder2)
```

In `folder1/folder2/CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
add_library(f2t1 bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(f2t1 f1t1)
```

Note that target names have to be *unique*, that's why I shortened and disambiguated them to `f1t1` etc.

Also refer to the documentation of [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). In this case, the linked `<item>` in the documentation is a *target name defined in the same project*. That means you can link `f2t1` in folder1 even though it has not yet been added.

Should you not provide a target `f2t1`, CMake will assume it's a *plain library name* and have the linker look it up. CMake will still work but it will eventually result in a linker error.

I left out header files as they are not needed for this simplistic example. In a real-world scenario, you would have header files and would want to make them accessible e.g. by calling `target_include_directories()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's starting to make sense. Yes, I was still thinking the bazel paradigm where each target is an "island" on its own, whereas CMake treats a directory and its subdirectories as a whole project.
I was under the wrong impression that you need to `add_subdirectoy` to reference a target in that directory. Now I understand that you can reference a target as long as it has been made visible to you one way or another (in this case, being added as a subdirectory by its parent directory).